# How can I filter items in a multidimensional array in JavaScript based on multiple indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i want to remove specific items from array of arrays in javascript
for example i have two arrays:

the first one "array1" contains arrays:

`[0: ['example', 'example'], 1: ['example1', 'example1'], 2: ['example2', 'example2']]`

and my second array "keys" contains only indexes which I need to remove from array1:
`[0,2]`

and i need to get only output:
`[1: ['example1', 'example1']]`

`for (let i = keys.length -1; i >= 0; i--) array1.splice(Number(keys[i]),1);`

I tried this but this return me oposite items

Comment: Any specific reason to use a multidimensional array instead of [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functional approach:

```
const result = array1.filter((element, index) => !keys.includes(index));
```

Filter all `array1` items that are included in `keys` array.